# Is there a way to consolidate overlapping scrolling bars?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

So I was working on trying to emulate the same scrolling effect found here in this [NYT story](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/03/14/climate/easter-island-erosion.html) in the hero section. I was able to get it somewhat working in my codepen but as you will see when you scroll up and down between the hero section and main text area the scroll bars collide/overlap. Wonder how best to address this and if there is a way to have one scroll bar like in the story. I also played around with adding `scrollbar-width: none;` but I don't think that's good UX and looks kind of weird when trying to scroll to top.

```css
.video-bg-container video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-position: center top;
}

.video-bg-container {
  position: absolute;
}

.video-text-container {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  .p-1 {
    margin-top: 40vh;
    margin-bottom: 80vh;
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  .p-2 {
    margin-bottom: 80vh;
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  .p-3 {
    margin-bottom: 80vh;
    background-color: tomato;
  }
}

.video-text {
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="video-bg-container">
    <video loop autoplay="true" muted="true" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"></video>
  </div>
  <div class="video-text-container">
    <div class="video-text">
      <div class="p-1">
        <p>Biltong rump venison shoulder capicola. Biltong bresaola picanha flank drumstick.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="p-2">
        <p>Biltong rump venison shoulder capicola. Biltong bresaola picanha flank drumstick.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="p-3">
        <p>Biltong rump venison shoulder capicola. Biltong bresaola picanha flank drumstick.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly. Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison. Brisket turkey
    pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
  <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly. Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison. Brisket turkey
    pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
  <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly. Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison. Brisket turkey
    pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
  <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly. Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison. Brisket turkey
    pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/phernand42/pen/abvoXab

Comment: in chrome you can simply hide the scrollbar and it'll work as expected, However other browsers don't support it, there's plenty of libraries out there for that.

Comment: Thanks Zohir. I wanted to do that at first but I think I may be bad UX to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Went a different route with this. I used a parallax approach for this particular case.

```
<div class="scroll-test">
    <div class="video-bg-container">
      <video loop autoplay="true" muted="true" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"></video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-text-container">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item-text">
          <p>Biltong rump venison shoulder capicola.  Biltong bresaola picanha flank drumstick.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item-text">
          <p>Biltong rump venison shoulder capicola.  Biltong bresaola picanha flank drumstick.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item-text">
          <p>Biltong rump venison shoulder capicola.  Biltong bresaola picanha flank drumstick.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="main-text">
    <div class="main-text--inner">
    <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly.  Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison.  Brisket turkey pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
    <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly.  Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison.  Brisket turkey pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
    <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly.  Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison.  Brisket turkey pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
    <p>Boudin capicola flank turkey ham, picanha tenderloin burgdoggen pig kielbasa leberkas ribeye pork belly.  Chuck salami meatloaf, sirloin flank kielbasa hamburger pork chop landjaeger brisket fatback tenderloin short loin short ribs venison.  Brisket turkey pork belly tongue drumstick swine shoulder shank tail ball tip cupim capicola hamburger spare ribs meatball.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.scroll-test {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.video-bg-container video {
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 56.25vw;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 177.77777778vh;
}

.video-bg-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.video-text-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 60vh;

  .field-items {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 40rem;
  }

  .field-item-text > div:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 65vh;
  }

  .field-item-text > div:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 10vh;
  }

  .field-item-text {
    margin-bottom: 65vh;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
 }

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;

  h1 {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
  }

  .main-text--inner {
    padding: 2rem;
  }

}
```

You can see a demo on my code pen. Hope this helps and open to any feedback to improve this

https://codepen.io/phernand42/pen/abvoXab